# Are the Ninja Gaiden games in the same universe?

Tags: video-games, ninja-gaiden

The original Ninja Gaiden games (1-3) were directly related. It featured Ryu Hyabusa traveling to the US after his father was killed.

Some 15 years later, Team Ninja released a new series of Ninja Gaiden games. The first one starts with Ryu Hyabusa's clan being attacked and killed. Without having finished the game, the story generally seemed at odds with the original story.

Are the two games series linked in any way but name and character name? Is there any sort of continuity between them?

Comment: *'Without having finished the game, the story generally seemed at odds with the original story.'* Then again the same with the third game ... Fond memories of the first two games but hardly bothered with the third. The first two were brilliantly done. I believe I've heard of the games you refer to but don't have a clue about them and that includes which consoles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the game's creator, Tomonobu Itagaki, the games in the Ninja Gaiden universe (the two new games and the earlier NES Trilogy) form a *single continuous story*

> **VideoGamer.com:** *We've read that this is the last chapter in the Ninja
> Gaiden saga. Is there any truth to that?*
>
> **TI:** *I really put all my heart and soul into making this the definitive
> game in the Ninja Gaiden franchise. So I personally don't intend to
> make any more. This is a game we basically built from the ground up.
> We threw away everything we had from the first game, improved on what
> was good, changed what was bad. So it's been a long project, it's been
> close to three years in the making. We were able to accomplish
> everything that we wanted to achieve with this franchise.*
>
> **In story chronology as well, this takes place after the first Ninja Gaiden for Xbox and then after, the story of this game it leads into the old NES ones, so I think we have a nice continuity there.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Ninja Gaiden 2 Preview](http://www.videogamer.com/xbox360/ninja_gaiden_2/preview-948.html)</sup></sub>

Obviously this doesn't account for some canon discontinuity, but that can be put down to production error.

Answer (score 5):

Officially, [they are in the same continuity](http://ninjagaiden.wikia.com/wiki/Biography_of_Ryu_Hayabusa) as the NES games with the XBox games operating as prequels.

> his continuity has been reworked to tie the classic Ninja Gaiden and current Ninja Gaiden titles together in the style of games such as Metal Gear and Metroid that rework their continuity to tie their current titles with their classic titles. Minor changes would have to occur such as character appearances and Jô Hayabusa would have to go by his name in the Japanese version Jô Hayabusa. This is done for those who want to see how they fit together, otherwise omit the classic Ninja Gaiden games in this timeline for a more simple continuity. Officially the continuities are tied together